# Hide GNOME top bar in activities

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-panel

I'm using Hide [Top Bar Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) to hide GNOME top bar but it cannot hide it in activities.

Normal desktop:

[image: Hide top bar]

Activities view:

[image: activities view]

Also tried [Hide Top Panel Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/740/hide-top-panel/), the same behavior.

and I couldn't find anything related to that on dconf editor.

How can I hide that?

Comment: Not possible likely without editing source code, or until someone comes up with an extension for that.